# Why are these solutions to wave equations not considered?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, waves, differential-equations

1. Do plane waves form a complete set (later edit: I meant basis)of solutions to the 3D wave equation ?
2. In this [reference](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Emille003/3Dhelmholtz.pdf), page 164, there is huge array of solutions. Can one write one set of solutions as a linear combination of the other ?
3. Solutions to the 3D Laplace equation such as

$1/r$
and
$x/(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}$

are also solutions of wave equation (edit after Andrews answer: after removing some points from full 3D space).
Lorentz boosted versions of these are also solutions of wave equations. Why are these not considered while writing down the general solutions to wave equations. Or is it that these can be expanded in plane waves ?

4. Lastly perhaps most importantly, if there are general solutions not expressible as linear combinations of plane waves, how do I see that the general solution will not carry signals faster than light ?

Comment: Sorry in q 1 I did mean complete basis set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do plane waves form a complete set of solutions to the 3D wave equation ?

They form a complete *basis*, not a complete *set*. Every solution to the wave equation is a superposition of plane waves, but not every solution is a plane wave.

> In this reference, page 164, there is huge array of solutions. Can one write one set of solutions as a linear combination of the other ?

For context, this table shows a list of coordinate systems in which the Helmholtz equation is separable. If $\phi(\vec{x},t)$ solves the full wave equation, and we look at solutions with a definite frequency $\phi(\vec{x},t) = f(\vec{x}) e^{i \omega t}$, then $f(\vec{x})$ solves the Helmholtz equation. It remains true that you can write $\phi(\vec{x},t)$ as a superposition of plane waves, for any solution $\phi$ of the wave equation. You also can write any solution of the Helmholtz equation, for a given $\omega$, as a superposition of basis functions derived in any of the coordinate systems used in that table. So, it turns out, yes you can write any of the solutions in that table as a linear superposition of the others.

> Solutions to the 3D Laplace equation such as
> 1/ and /(2+2+2)3/2
> are also solutions of wave equation.

This is not correct. Perhaps what you had in mind is that $\sin\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}\right)/r$ is a solution of the Helmholtz equation, for $|\vec{k}| = \pm \omega/c$.

> Lastly perhaps most importantly, if there are general solutions not expressible as linear combinations of plane waves, how do I see that the general solution will not carry signals faster than light ?

Since all solutions are linear combinations of plane waves, the premise of this question is false.

Comment: About Q3. These are not time dependent. so the time derivatives of the wave equation vanish. Then I am left with the laplacian. These functions are annihilated by the laplacian.

Comment: @symanzik138 The wave equation is $-\partial_t^2 \phi + \nabla^2 \phi = 0$, so if $\phi$ is constant in time then $\nabla^2\phi = 0$. But $\nabla^2(1/r) = -4\pi \delta^3(\vec{x}) \neq 0$, so does not solve the wave equation. Incidentally, I made an error in my original answer by saying that $e^{\pm i k r}/r$ solves the Helmholtz equation. Really only $\sin(k r)/r$ (the 0-th spherical bessel function) does. As $\omega\rightarrow 0$, then $k\rightarrow 0$, and $\sin(kr)/r \rightarrow 0$; this is another way to see $1/r$ is not a solution of the wave equation when the time dependence vanishes.

Comment: You can say $1/r$ is a solution to the Laplace equation with a source (the Poisson equation). But this is not the same thing as the Laplace equation. That's why $/1r$ is not considered as a solution of Laplace's equation / the wave equation.

Comment: Thanks. So if I consider a region with origin removed, there are these additional solutions ? Sorry for incrementally changing the question. I will add the edit in the question.

Comment: @symanzik138 The space of solutions depends on the boundary conditions. So you can end up with gaining or losing solutions by doing something like removing a point at the origin. Specifically in that case, you would no longer require that the solutions are regular at the origin, so $\cos(k r)/r$ would be a solution to the Helmholtz equation in addition to $\sin(kr)/r$ (in addition to superpositions of those). Then taking the $k\rightarrow 0$ limit you would get the $1/r$ solution.